# Can I prevent tree expand and collapse in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabulator

I am using the Tabulator plugin to display a tree of data and allow user edits. However, I do not want to allow users to collapse and expand the tree (this causes problems for dragging and dropping rows and subsequent redraws). Is it possible to prevent tree collapse and expand?

extract of code below:

```
    table = new Tabulator("#ModuleList", {
    data:treeData, // JSON dataset - loads and displays no problem
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded:true,
layout:"fitDataTable",
movableRows:true,
dataTreeElementColumn:"blank",
dataTreeCollapseElement:false, // wild guess but no impact
    columns:[
        {title:"", field:"blank", headerSort:false},
        {title:"Ref", field:"itemref", editor:true, headerSort:false},
        {title:"Item", field:"title", editor:true, headerSort:false},
        {title:"Weighting", field:"weighting", editor:true, validator:["min:0", "max:100", "numeric"], headerSort:false},
        {title:"Default Score", field:"defaultscore", editor:true, validator:["min:" + document.getElementById("ModelMinScore").value, "max:" + document.getElementById("ModelMaxScore").value, "numeric"], headerSort:false},
        {title:"Target Score", field:"targetscore", editor:true, validator:["min:" + document.getElementById("ModelMinScore").value, "max:" + document.getElementById("ModelMaxScore").value, "numeric"], headerSort:false},
            ],});
```